# Is "If I was just counting the number of people" apt in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conditional-constructions, subjunctives

> Rui: Hey, Momo. Um, do you have plenty of experience being in
>   relationships?
>
> Momo: Did you hear that from someone? I wouldn't call it plenty, but
>   **If I was just counting the number of people**... Thirty people... or so?
>
> Rui: ...
>
> Momo: Oh, but not two at the same time, you knw? I do break up
>   properly before going out again.

Is that happy in the context? I would hazard a guess that "**If I am just counting the number of people**" is more apt than "**If I was just counting the number of people**" in the context.

My thoughts bare on the concept that "past tenses" in *If clauses* relate to unreal situations, or unlikely situations. But, *If clause* in the context seems to rest on a common assumption that is likely to be real. In fact, after enunciating the *if clause*, she, Momo counted and uttered the number of people that she had been on intimate terms with. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textbooks might tell you that you always use *were* in a subjunctive... but that's because they are often based on formal grammar rules that few obey in reality.

This *was* is part of a subjunctive. It is phrased as a hypothetical. The fact she then goes on to state a number may seem to indicate that she has done the count in her head, albeit approximately.

You may think of it as "If I were just counting the number of people I've been in a relationship with, I would get to about 30 or so".

She hasn't counted out aloud, but she may have counted in her head. More likely she estimated roughly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought "If I [am] just counting the number of people" is more apt than "If I [was] just counting~" in the context in order to mean it's just a hypotetical situation. To my knowledge, "If I [win], they will live to regret it" is a possible hypothesis. Yet, "If I [won], they would live to regret it" is an impractical/unlikely hypothesis.

Comment: Thus, in the situation, I'd like to prefer "If I [am] counting the number~" or "If I [count] the number~" to "If I [was/were] counting the number~".  That is to say, I feel like prefering "present tense" to "past tense" in the If clause. Would you correct me If I am wrong?

Comment: The "was" or "were" isn't indicating the past tense in this case. It's indicating the subjunctive. "If I'm counting" is not something most people would say is *wrong*, but "If I was/were" is more common in my experience. People who get stuffy about formal grammar might say "If I'm counting" is wrong, I'm not sure. If I look at it analytically, it could be setting a condition rather than expressing a hypothetical. However, the was/were often drops out of expressions in general usage, possibly because similar expressions exist where it isn't used.

Comment: I'm immensely grateful for your help. I'll keep in mind "setting a condition". Quite so.